PowerBI - USA map colored by Electric Markets (RTOs, ISOs)
I want to color a map in Power BI depending on the electrical markets (MISO, PJM, NYISO, ERCOT, CAISO,...)
Since these markets don't match exactly the boundaries of the counties, I haven't been able to find a map that can be colored with these requirements. Is there any option available to meet my needs?
Thanks,
Searching in other forums and videos in yt.

Post a picture, please, we don't understand
